# How to give each MySQL user there own FullCalendar on the same page?

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar for the first time and would like to know if there is a way to provide each MySQL user with there own private calendar?

Basically I have created a website where the calendar is displayed and you can add events, drag events and delete events. But I would like to make it so each user on the MySQL table has there own calendar that only they could see and modify events.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: When saving an event, make sure you also store what user it belongs tot (add a `user_id` column in the event table that you store the current user id). Then when you select and update, you make sure you only select and update the events that belongs to the current user (something like `WHERE user_id = ?` in your queries). If you're just getting started with Mysql, I would highly recommend reading some "get started with relational databases" guides and tutorials to understand how they work and how to structure your data. It will def. help you with cases like this going forward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also wanted to ask if there is a way for the id to be from another table in the same database. So both tables sync the id. As I have one user table which is used to sync users info on the whole site and then I have the calendar table which is just used for FullCalendar.

Comment: Yes, that's the user id you should store in the calendar table, the user id from the users table. That creates a _relation_ between the records in the database and is the one of the most fundamental parts of _relational_ databases. So again, I would _strongly_ recommend you to read up on how relational databases work and on how to properly use them.

Comment: So I went ahead and researched about it and that's exactly what I have been searching for so thank you. But, again sorry for bothering you or asking dumb questions. But I used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lH9ZwAsvWM&ab_channel=Webslesson to setup my mysql connection of fullcalendar to the table. Now I just wanted to confirm and ask that for me to select the id from the users table and store the events id with the user id I have to do that in the load.php part right? Where the fullcalendar loads from the sql. It would be really helpful if you can link an example too.

Comment: If you have more question, please post is as another question where you include all relevant information, like the relevant parts of the code, the table schemas, example data and such. I'm not going to look through a youtube video.